# App store Rejected me from the app crashing but it has never crashed for me through numerous testing

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I submitted my app to the app store, but they rejected it saying that the app crashed when they clicked the feedback button which is a button that opens up a MFMailComposeViewController. The problem I am having is I have run it on many devices between the simulator and actual devices, yet I have never had this problem. I will post my functions for the feedback button below which I have called and are all connected to the button (Like I said it works completely fine every time I have tested it), and my question is: Am i doing something wrong in the code to where only they get the crash?

```
func giveFeedback()
{
    let email = ["info@website.com"]
    var fvc = view?.window?.rootViewController
    var cev = MFMailComposeViewController()
    cev.mailComposeDelegate = self
    cev.setToRecipients(email)
    cev.setSubject("MyApp")
    fvc?.presentViewController(cev, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!)
{
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Also, I have imported `MessageUI`, and in the class I have my `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`

Comment: Did they provide a stack trace?

Comment: I have detailed crash logs, is that the same thing?

Comment: If the crash log is symbolicated, it should contain a useful stack trace.

Comment: And more to the point, the useful stack trace will tell you exactly where the app was when it crashed. It may not tell you exactly *why* it crashed in a larger sense, but knowing what code directly resulted in the crash should point you in the right direction. If you can't figure it out, edit your question to include the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is that you don't call [canSendMail](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMailComposeViewController/canSendMail). I believe that if you try to show the MFMailComposeViewController when mails are disabled, your app would crash.

In your function you would use it for example like this:

```
func giveFeedback(contextViewController: UIViewController) {

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let email = ["info@website.com"]
        var cev = MFMailComposeViewController()
        cev.mailComposeDelegate = self
        cev.setToRecipients(email)
        cev.setSubject("MyApp")
        contextViewController.presentViewController(cev, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But it would be best to check the status earlier and display the button only if email is enabled on the device...

Comment: I've never used canSendMail, how would i use it in this case?

Comment: I updated the answer. I also fixed the link to documentation.

Comment: Don't forget to handle the case there `canSendMail` is false. Either test it before showing the UI to send feedback, or instead open Safari to a web view/contact form on your web site.

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna try this out and keep my fingers crossed but it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well I will have to guess too.... There are two things that look suspicious to me... the first thing is the line

```
var fvc = view?.window?.rootViewController
```

could you change it this way?

```
func giveFeedback(contextViewController: UIViewController) {
    let email = ["info@website.com"]
    var cev = MFMailComposeViewController()
    cev.mailComposeDelegate = self
    cev.setToRecipients(email)
    cev.setSubject("MyApp")
    contextViewController.presentViewController(cev, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```